# mysql sorting alphanumeric transaction code using date indicator

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have some data

```
SMMP0220113042212
SMMP0220113042211
SMMP0220113042210
SMMP022011304231
SMMP022011304229
SMMP022011304228
```

How query i must create to make if, "SMMP02201" is store code, "130422" is date (yymmdd), after that code is increment transaction for a day

```
SMMP022011304231
SMMP0220113042212
SMMP0220113042211
SMMP0220113042210
SMMP022011304229
SMMP022011304228
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT code
FROM table
ORDER BY substr(code, 1, 9), SUBSTR(code, 10, 6) DESC, CAST(substr(code, 16) AS DECIMAL) DESC;
```

[FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f362/1)